# KotlinAPP crashes at toLong() conversion

Tags: string, kotlin, split, crash

First, i'm new here and i hope, that i have done all ok with my first question.
As ist is my first post here, i would like to introduce myself shortly.
I'm a 53 year old C-Programmer from Germany who is trying to learn app-programming by using Kotlin.

In my first Project my App crashes as i try to convert a String into a Long.

```
var actualTimer = binding.textTimer.text.toString()
                var tmpList = actualTimer.split(":").toTypedArray()

                var minutes = tmpList[0].toLong()
                var seconds = tmpList[1].toLong()
```

The textTimer is a PlainText-View including a CountdownTimer in "mm:ss" Format.

My goal ist to split the String from the View into minutes and seconds to convert and sum them to milliseconds to initialize my CountdownTimer.

I hope these Information is enough to solve my Problem. If there is something missing, please tell me.
Thanks in advance

Martin

I have searched the Internet but didn't find a solution

Comment: What do you mean by ‘crash’? What error message does it give? (I'm betting it's a NumberFormatException…)

Comment: Omg, sometimes it is so easy. I locked after the error message an i saw, that in both strings are blankspaces! At the start and the end of each. Deleted them and the conversion worked fine...

Comment: I guess that should be Rule Number One of debugging: **look**. Look at exactly what you did, look at exactly what happened, and especially **look at any error message, stack trace, or other logs**. In Kotlin and Java, there's usually an exception message, often with a stack trace, and that will usually tell you all you need to know — or if not, where to look, and narrow down the probnlem.